# Shimming in Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, module, polyfills

I am reading Shimming from the official docs. of `Webpack`, but still I'm unable to get what it means ?

As I am new to Webpack, I have also tried to do some `RND`, but I could not get the proper answer from that. I have few questions about `Shimming` which are as follow :

- What is `Shimming` ?
- What does `Shimming` does actually ?
- Why there is need of `Shimming` in webpack ?
- How it works ?
- Pros and cons of `Shimming`.

If anyone knows, even few answers of the questions mentioned above, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some libraries depend on global variables. For example, a jQuery plugin may expect the "$" global variable to be available.

Without shimming that variable with `ProvidePlugin` you would get an error `$ is not defined`.

In simple terms shimming would replace all global `$` variables in JavaScript modules with `require('jquery')`. In some legacy libraries you would also need to shim `jQuery` or `window.$` because the plugin only performs a basic text replacement.

You only need shimming for libraries or any code you do not have control over. In the application modules you should import jQuery with `import $ from 'jquery'` and avoid global variables.

Comment: Okay thank you for your response, I understood the concept, but if you can also explain, that how it works, I mean behind the hood, than it will also be accepted...